# Is it possible to know if the type of the uploaded file is an image?

Tags: asp.net, javascript, image, file-upload

While user uploading a file, is it possible to know if the uploaded file is an image or not,

I am open for any solution, Client Side, Server Side or both and we choose based on the case.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, by checking the [magic number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)) of the file.

Answer (score 2):

May be you can use following code to check if the file is an image.

```
public bool IsFileAnImage(string filePath)
{
   try
   {
      Image image = Image.FromFile(filePath))
   }
   catch
   {
      return false;   
   }
   finally
   {
      image.Dispose();
   }

   return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done server side with GD by using the function below: ([(modified version of this)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2207095/get-image-mimetype-from-resource-in-php-gd)

```
function imageFileTypeFromBinary($file)
{

    $binary = file_get_contents($file);

    if (
        !preg_match(
            '/\A(?:(\xff\xd8\xff)|(GIF8[79]a)|(\x89PNG\x0d\x0a)|(BM)|(\x49\x49(\x2a\x00|\x00\x4a))|(FORM.{4}ILBM))/',
            $binary, $hits
        )
    ) {
        return 'application/octet-stream';
            //return false;

    }
    static $type = array (
        1 => '.jpeg',
        2 => '.gif',
        3 => '.png',
        4 => '.x-windows-bmp',
        5 => '.tiff',
        6 => '.x-ilbm',
    );
    return $type[count($hits) - 1];
    // or simply return true
    // return true;
}
```

should you wish, you can make it return true, or false as opposed to the mime type.

Answer (score -2):

A simple way would be to look at the file's extension.

Comment: That tells you nothing other than the extension; and is a common way for sites to erroneously allow executables to be uploaded.

Comment: I did say "simple", as opposed to foolproof, but I would suggest that file extension is valuable even if you're concerned that the user would lie.  If a user renames virus.exe to funpic.gif, then the extension is making a false promise.  However, since it claims to be a gif, we can then test specifically for whether it really is, rejecting it otherwise. Otherwise, we'd have to exhaust all possibilities.

Comment: I should probably add that renaming the extension can *make* a dangerous file harmless.  For example, a `*.VBS` file that destroys the file system is merely interesting reading when renamed to `*.TXT`.