# Get image mimetype from resource in PHP/GD?

Tags: php, image, ftp, gd

I'm trying to find the mime type of an image. PHP has the function `getimagesize` but that only takes a filename, whereas I have an image "resource" instead - i.e. an image created from `imagecreatefromstring`.

I found the functions `imagesx` and `imagesy` which return the width/height from a resource but I can't find any function that tell me the mime type from a resource. Anyone know of a way to do this?

Note: Due to a weird server set up, we **can't read/write files** from the server normally, only through an FTP layer (which is where I read the image data from).

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965689/php-gd-finding-image-resource-type

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.image-type-to-mime-type.php

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I know this is pretty old, but just in case someone come across this post like I did...

A better option it's been released from PHP 5.4.0:
[getimagesizefromstring](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.getimagesizefromstring.php)

This new function is exactly the same of getimagesize but allows you to retreive the information from a stream.

Answer (score 14):

If you've got access to the binary data of the image (as the use of imagecreatefromstring() suggests), you can detect the file-type "manually":

```
function image_file_type_from_binary($binary) {
    if (
        !preg_match(
            '/\A(?:(\xff\xd8\xff)|(GIF8[79]a)|(\x89PNG\x0d\x0a)|(BM)|(\x49\x49(?:\x2a\x00|\x00\x4a))|(FORM.{4}ILBM))/',
            $binary, $hits
        )
    ) {
        return 'application/octet-stream';
    }
    static $type = array (
        1 => 'image/jpeg',
        2 => 'image/gif',
        3 => 'image/png',
        4 => 'image/x-windows-bmp',
        5 => 'image/tiff',
        6 => 'image/x-ilbm',
    );
    return $type[count($hits) - 1];
}
```

Abusing a stream wrapper gets a bit more complicated. 
At least if we don't want to fiddle with global variables.

```
// getimagesize() from string
class GisFromString {
    const proto_default = 'gisfromstring';
    protected static $proto = null;
    protected static $imgdata = null;

    static function getImageSize($imgdata) {
        if (null === self::$proto) {
            self::register();
        }
        self::$imgdata = $imgdata;
        // note: @ suppresses "Read error!" notices if $imgdata isn't valid
        return @getimagesize(self::$proto . '://');
    }

    static function getMimeType($imgdata) {
        return is_array($gis = self::getImageSize($imgdata))
            ? $gis['mime']
            : $gis;
    }

    // streamwrapper helper:

    const unregister = null;

    // register|unregister wrapper for the given protocol|scheme
    // return registered protocol or null
    static function register(
        $proto = self::proto_default // protocol or scheme
    ) {
        if (self::unregister === $proto) { // unregister if possible
            if (null === self::$proto) {
                return null;
            }
            if (!stream_wrapper_unregister(self::$proto)) {
                return null;
            }
            $return = self::$proto;
            self::$proto = null;
            return $return;
        }
        if (!preg_match('/\A([a-zA-Z][a-zA-Z0-9.+\-]*)(:([\/\x5c]{0,3}))?/', $proto, $h)) {
            throw new Exception(
                sprintf('could not register invalid scheme or protocol name "%s" as streamwrapper', $proto)
            );
        }
        if (!stream_wrapper_register($proto = $h[1], __CLASS__)) {
            throw new Exception(
                sprintf('protocol "%s" already registered as streamwrapper', $proto)
            );
        }
        return self::$proto = $proto;
    }

    // streamwrapper API:

    function stream_open($path, $mode) {
        $this->str = (string) self::$imgdata;
        $this->fsize = strlen($this->str);
        $this->fpos = 0;
        return true;
    }

    function stream_close() {
        self::$imgdata = null;
    }

    function stream_read($num_bytes) {
        if (!is_numeric($num_bytes) || $num_bytes < 1) {
            return false;
        }
        /* uncomment this if needed
        if ($this->fpos + $num_bytes > 65540 * 4) {
            // prevent getimagesize() from scanning the whole file
            // 65_540 is the maximum possible bytesize of a JPEG segment
            return false;
        }
        */
        if ($this->fpos + $num_bytes > $this->fsize) {
            $num_bytes = $this->fsize - $this->fpos;
        }
        $read = substr($this->str, $this->fpos, $num_bytes);
        $this->fpos += strlen($read);
        return $read;
    }

    function stream_eof() {
        return $this->fpos >= $this->fsize;
    }

    function stream_tell() {
        return $this->fpos;
    }

    function stream_seek($off, $whence = SEEK_SET) {
        if (SEEK_CUR === $whence) {
            $off = $this->fpos + $off;
        }
        elseif (SEEK_END === $whence) {
            $off = $this->fsize + $off;
        }
        if ($off < 0 || $off > $this->fsize) {
            return false;
        }
        $this->fpos = $off;
        return true;
    }
}


// usage:
//$imgdata = file_get_contents('path/lenna.jpg');


// if the default protocol is already registered
//GisFromString::register('other');

var_dump(GisFromString::getImageSize($imgdata));

echo GisFromString::getMimeType($imgdata);
```

Comment: The function `image_file_type_from_binary` is not failsafe. sometimes a file is being uploaded but the mimetype is not an image/<type>. make the preg_match case insensitive by adding an 'i' after the ending forward-slash. (made the change in above script, but have to wait for aproval) the use of this function is a good one since not all webhosts allow you to use fileinfo or exif extensions...

Comment: Of course it is not failsafe. It only checks the "magic bytes" at the beginning of the imagedata. Appending "/i" to the regex is a rather bad idea. Binary files have no notion of "case awareness".

Answer (score 11):

An image created using `imagecreatefromstring` has no MIME type any more, it is decoded from its native format and stored in GD's internal format.

The same question was [**asked a while back**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1965689/php-gd-finding-image-resource-type) with the same result.

The only way to go is to catch the image before it gets `imagecreatefromstring`ed, and somehow catch the size information from it.

You say that you can't do file read/write operations on your system, so just writing out the file is out of the question.

The fact that getimagesize() can't read from variables is known and lamented: http://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=44239

The guy there mentions a nifty workaround: [**Registering a new stream wrapper that allows file operations on variables**](http://php.net/manual/en/stream.streamwrapper.example-1.php).

Is this an option on your server setup?

Comment: Sorry, like I said I can't read/write files to the server normally, so it's not possible to use `getimagesize` because there is no filename. EDIT: dude, don't be so impatient, I was writing an explanation... ;)

Comment: Can't be done with a GD resource only, sorry. But if you `imagecreatefromstring`, you have the original data at some point, right? Why not write it out to disk and do a `getimagesize`? I agree it's silly, but it'll do the job. EDIT: That's why I first comment and then vote ;) Second edit: Ah, you can't write to disk. And I take it you can't use the `ftp://` wrapper for imagesize()?

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat, I added a second possibility.

Comment: FWIW, I just ran into this as well. PHP 5.3 is not available currently so `getimagesizefromstring()` is not an option (nor is `FileInfo`), and I didn't want to complicate the implementation with the `VariableStream` wrapper. The next best thing is using the `data://` wrapper, which allows you to create an in-memory URI that `getimagesize()` can read. It also optimizes the request by only encoding a small substring of the binary data. The gist of the implementation is here: https://gist.github.com/3751491

Answer (score 1):

You could use the PHP fileinfo functions.

```
$image_buffer = SomeFunctionToGetStringBufferFromGD();

$fileinfo = finfo_open();

$type = finfo_buffer($fileinfo, $image_buffer);
```

It uses the [magic numbers](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format#Magic_number) (same as the unix file command) to identify the file type.

Comment: This works great. The only downside is it returns a string you'd have to parse further to get a mime type, eg. `PNG image, 28 x 18, 8-bit colormap, non-interlaced`