# Validation of Base64 encoded image

Tags: php

In my *cakephp* program, I am converting a *base64 encoded image* to an image and then storing it in a folder.

How can I validate this image, before conversion?

The string is like `data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG.....`.
(The image can be of any extension not only png.)

Comment: http://codeaid.net/php/check-if-the-file-is-a-png-image-file-by-reading-its-signature

Comment: You want to validate the image before you convert to base64? What are you validating against, in that case?

Comment: Its an API in PHP for an IOS app.Im getting base 64 encrypted image , i just want to validate it and convert it to image and store it in a folder.Conversion working fine.How can i validate this encoded image

Answer (score 1):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11511605/3862372) might be useful for *processing* the image.
[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12658754/3862372) might be useful for *validating* the image.

Code:

```
$data = 'data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KG.....';

list($type, $data) = explode(';base64,', $data, 2);
$data = str_replace(' ', '+', $data);
$data = base64_decode($data);

if (imagecreatefromstring($data) == false) { echo "invalid_image"; die(); }

file_put_contents('/storage/folder/image.png', $data);
```

You might also want to restrict file types.

You must keep in mind that you can't simply trust any of the data sent from the client (like 'data:image/png'), so you must rely on other means (some *php* functions).