# Laravel - Convert a base64 string to a valid image

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

To give you a grasp of what I am trying to do, here is my current code

*This code is run when a post request is made to specific URL*

```
public function uploadImage(Request $request) {
    $request->file = base64_decode(explode(',', $request->file)[1]);

    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'image|required|mimes:jpg,png',
    ]);

    $image = $request->file('file');

    $complete = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $name = pathinfo($complete, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $storageName = $name.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

    Storage::disk('public')->put($storageName, File::get($image));

    return Storage::disk('public')->path($storageName);
}
```

On the first line I am trying to be smart and first decode the base64 to a file (if I am correct?).

Next is a validation to validate if the `file` parameter in the request exists, is an image, and is a `.jpg` or `.png`

(The next lines is just about saving the "image" to the filesystem)

But the validation won't pass because the `file` parameter is not an image. So my question is: is it possible to convert a base64 string to a valid image in Laravel? If it is, how can this be achieved?

Comment: Look at PHP's GD library...  specifically http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagecreatefromstring.php

Answer (score 1):

> You can valid image **base64** 
> please follow me step by step :

1 . Go to folder yourProjectName\app\Providers\AppServiceProvider.php 
2 . copy this code and past in this file at function **boot()**

```php
Validator::extend('is_image', function ($attribute, $value, $parameters, $validator) {
        preg_match_all('/([^\.]+)\.([a-zA-Z]+)/',$value,$matchedExt);
        if (isset($matchedExt[2][0]) && in_array($matchedExt[2][0],$parameters)) return true;
        preg_match_all('/data\:image\/([a-zA-Z]+)\;base64/',$value,$matched);
        $ext = isset($matched[1][0]) ? $matched[1][0] : false;
        print_r($value);
        return in_array($ext,$parameters) ? true : false;
});
```

3. Go to your function uploadImage() and past this code

```php
public function uploadImage(Request $request) {
    
    $request->validate([
        'file' => 'image|required|is_image:jpg,png',
    ]);

    $image = $request->file('file');

    $complete = $image->getClientOriginalName();
    $name = pathinfo($complete, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
    $extension = $image->getClientOriginalExtension();
    $storageName = $name.'_'.time().'.'.$extension;

    Storage::disk('public')->put($storageName, File::get($image));

    return Storage::disk('public')->path($storageName);
}
```

I hope I'll solve the problem for you

Answer (score 0):

Laravel can't resolve your base 64 string to a file, hence the failure of the file validator. You also won't be able to access your data with `->file('file')`, since again, you're not sending over a valid file upload.

Instead, you could do your own simple string check (perhaps index of `data:image` or preferably something more extensive, like [`imagecreatefromstring`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12658754/2535504)) or look into [writing a custom Laravel validation rule](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/validation#custom-validation-rules), and then save the sent string into a file with [`file_put_contents`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php).

If you're actually wanting to do a file upload and convert that to base 64 on the server side, then you'll want to use an `<input type="file">`. From there, you'll be able to use built-in Laravel validation and file storage functions. [Refer to this extensive guide.](https://scotch.io/tutorials/understanding-and-working-with-files-in-laravel) Once you've gotten your file, you can convert it to base64 using `base64_encode` ([see this answer for a more thorough guide](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13758760/2535504)).

I realize this answer wasn't very specific, but if you clarify exactly what you're trying to do, I can give more hands-on guidance.

Answer (score -1):

I'm using this code to convert a base64 string to an image :

```
    public function getImage($img, $pid)
{
    if($img == "")
        return null;
    $imagecode = base64_decode($img);

    $directory = public_path('img/uploads/x' . $pid);
    if (!file_exists($directory))
        \File::makeDirectory($directory);
    $id = uniqid('img_');
    $filename = time() . '-' . $id . '.png';
    $path = public_path('img/uploads/product_img/p' . $pid . '/' . $filename);
    $tpath = public_path('img/uploads/product_img/p' . $pid . '/small-' . $filename);

    try {
        $image = Image::make($imagecode)->widen(600, function ($constraint) {
            $constraint->upsize();
        })->save($path);
        $image->fit(200, 200)->save($tpath);
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        return null;
    }

    return "x" . $pid . "/" . $filename;
}
```