# any way to check what is wrong with base64 code

Tags: php, base64, jpeg

I have some `jpeg` images as `base64` encoded

I checked the `mime type` this way

```
$str = "..."; // base64 code

$imgdata = base64_decode($str);

$f = finfo_open();

$mime = finfo_buffer($f, $imgdata, FILEINFO_MIME_TYPE);

echo $mime . '<br><br>';
```

result - `image/jpeg`

Trying to display the image

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo $str; ?>" alt="img">
```

result - there is no any image

```
echo $str;
```

result - base64 code is echoed

is there any way to check what is wrong with the `base64` code

here is a live example - https://abuena.net/base.php

Comment: If abuena is your site I suggest you to remove the link and just post a picture of it, as it can hurt your server's CPU if it keeps loading with no ending. People might abuse it when they see the link

Comment: Why use base64 in the first place?  Why not serve your image from PHP code directly?  It's much more efficient.

Comment: @Brad, I have not original image saved, only the code

Comment: @Mootje, thanks a lot but on the page image the code would not be visible

Comment: make sure your base64 encoded image is valid by creating the image . this post might help you on how to validate image of base64 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12658661/validating-base64-encoded-images

Comment: @Al-Amin - yes, the code is not valid. Trying to open in GIMP - and getting the error - `Corrupt JPEG data: 298 extraneous bytes before marker 0x36`

Answer (score 0):

```
<img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?php echo $str; ?>" alt="img">
```

There should be no whitespace after "base64," - if that's not only a typo, it's likely the reason for the image not being shown.

Comment: I remove the white space - the same result

Comment: Your image is broken initially

Comment: yes, and that's my question - what is broken and how to repair, if possible

Comment: save the image data unencoded to file and open it in a graphic editor... maybe it can tell you or repair it...

Comment: Trying to open in GIMP - and getting the error - `Corrupt JPEG data: 298 extraneous bytes before marker 0x36`